# Почему не подключается фон к адаптивной версии?

Tags: css, mobile, background

```
@media (max-width: 485px) and (min-width: 320px){

body, html {
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

}

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/rWZVXe?editors=110  всё работает , сдвиньте там панель до вашего запроса, у вас 100% путь до изображения ни верный

Comment: Что указано в meta? Или замените max-width на max-device-width. [Для изучения](https://habrahabr.ru/company/paysto/blog/254871/)

Comment: ничего не помогло(

Comment: у меня все работает, стиль применяется при ширине браузера от 320 до 485px, если не отображается картинка, то дело в ее адресе.